# Saving Overpass-turbo query results to GeoJSON file with Python - to work on with the dataset

Tags: python, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

Saving Overpass query results to GeoJSON file with Python

want to create a leaflet - that shows the data of German schools

**background:** I have just started to use Python and I would like to make a query to Overpass and store the results in a geospatial format (e.g. GeoJSON). As far as I know, there is a library called overpy that should be what I am looking for. After reading its documentation I came up with the following little tiny code:

```
geojson_school_map

import overpy
import json

API = overpy.Overpass()

# Fetch schools in Germany
result = API.query("""
[out:json][timeout:250];
{{geocodeArea:Deutschland}}->.searchArea;
nwr[amenity=school][!"isced:level"](area.searchArea);
out geom;
""")

# Create a GeoJSON dictionary to store the features
geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
}

# Iterate over the result and extract relevant information
for node in result.nodes:
    # Extract coordinates
    lon = float(node.lon)
    lat = float(node.lat)

    # Create a GeoJSON feature for each node
    feature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [lon, lat]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": node.tags.get("name", "Unnamed School"),
            "amenity": node.tags.get("amenity", "school")
            # Add more properties as needed
        }
    }

    # Append the feature to the feature list
    geojson["features"].append(feature)

# Write the GeoJSON to a file
with open("schools.geojson", "w") as f:
    json.dump(geojson, f)

print("GeoJSON file created successfully!")
```

i will add take the data of the query the Overpass API for schools in Germany,

After extraction of the relevant information such as coordinates and school names, i will subsequently then convert this data into GeoJSON format.
Finally, it will write the GeoJSON data to a file named "schools.geojson".

well with that i will try to adjust the properties included in the GeoJSON as needed.

so see my **results** i get back on **google-colab:**

```
verpassBadRequest                        Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-f0918b7fb5d0> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 
      6 # Fetch schools in Germany
----> 7 result = API.query("""
      8 [out:json][timeout:250];
      9 {{geocodeArea:Deutschland}}->.searchArea;

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/overpy/__init__.py in query(self, query)
    173                 )
    174                 if not do_retry:
--> 175                     raise current_exception
    176                 retry_exceptions.append(current_exception)
    177                 continue

OverpassBadRequest: Error: line 3: parse error: Unknown type &quot;{&quot; 
Error: line 3: parse error: An empty query is not allowed 
Error: line 3: parse error: ';' expected - '{' found.
```

Comment: Same question was also posted here: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/saving-overpass-query-results-to-geojson-file-with-python-to-work-on-with-the-data/111159